# Oracle APEX - Refresh parent page 1 (interactive report) after closing a another page 2 (page mode = Modal dialog)

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am trying to refresh the interactive report on a parent page 1 after updating page 2 which is a modal dialog page mode. The page should close automatically after clicking the submit button (managed by a dynamic action). currently I have "apex.navigation.dialog.close(true);"  as the last sequence of Dynamic true action on the modal page 2.

I also created a DA on the parent page to execute javascript code "$('#myirr').trigger('apexrefresh'); " 
where #myirr is the static ID of the interactive report i want refreshed automatically. This did not work for me. Please can anyone give me some advice?  Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: What APEX version are you using?

Comment: I am using version 19.1